# Is it necessary to encrypt/encode an ASP.NET view state hidden field when using SSL certificate?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, base64, viewstate, encode

If you have an SSL certificate for a web site, is it necessary to make the ViewState more difficult to decode. Without any extra development, it appears that ASP.NET encodes it as a base 64 string. I found some sample code to easily decode this hidden field "__VIEWSTATE". Doesn't SSL encrypt this (along with other things) for you?

PS: If this is the incorrect site to post this question, please let me know.  I also have it on the Security site, but I don't know how much they know about web applications and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL will encrypt the data during *transport*. When the data is moving between the server and browser, including the view state.

It is up to you to do more on the page, if you feel the need. At the point that a browser is viewing the page, it has been transferred securely to the browser - do you feel that you need to protect the view state from the person using the browser?

Comment: Ah, I understand your point.  All the data in there is visible to that user anyway (in my situation--I think haha), so in my case, I don't think I need to.  So only if there was global data in the viewstate (or information critical for them to get outside the scope of what they're seeing) then it's necessary to encrypt it on top of what ASP.NET already does so you can't even see it in the browser HTML source?

Comment: @Mr. MacGyver - If the data you store is sensitive in nature, you shouldn't store it in ViewState. Doesn't matter if it is global or not.

Comment: I will have to check the EnableViewState attribute on our controls to be sure.  We definitely have social security numbers in there, but not sure if it's in viewstate.

Comment: I guess what i'm worried about is someone having a tool (like a browser plug-in) that can modify the data after it's rendered) and submit data back to the server based on that viewstate data (or any data in the page) after they modify it without using the browser to do it.  Not sure if such a tool exists.  We have security containers to protect certain pages from certain users in our application, and certain controls are shared between pages, so those must be filtered for certain users.  So that's what I'm most worried about.

Comment: @Mr. MacGyver - Such things are possible. One reason why you shouldn't store anything sensitive in ViewState.

Answer (score 1):

[You should not store sensitive data in the ViewState, ever!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649487.aspx#pagguidelines0001_avoidstoringsensitivedatainviewstate)

---

**Addendum**

If you're not storing sensitive data in the ViewState, then don't worry about encrypting or decrypting it. It will just add unnecessary overhead.

Comment: The OP says nothing about storing sensitive data in ViewState.